# Howto CSS: two elements, both vertically centered, floating to opposite sides (Example)

Tags: html, css

To Put it simple, I would like a header with two elements floating to each side and vertically centered:

[image]

I started out with doing this with non-floating elements and managed to make [this example](http://jsbin.com/azaxus/1/edit).

But once I add the `float:left` or `float:right` the vertical centering is lost (I understand why, because it's not part of the flow anymore)

I wonder what is the best method to achieve this. Complete CSS redesign is happily accepted.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vertical centering can be painful, especially when you are not dealing with inline elements.  In this case, I would recommend taking advantage of `display:table-cell`.

**HTML**

```
       <div id="wrapper">
            <div class="cell">
                <div class="content">
                    Content Goes here
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="cell">
                <div class="content2">
                    <div class="redbox">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**CSS**

```
            #wrapper {
                color: white;
                display: table;
                border: 1px solid darkblue;
                background: blue;
                width: 100%;
            }

            .cell {
                display: table-cell;
                vertical-align: middle;
                height: 200px;
            }

            .content {
                float: left;
            }

            .content2{
                float: right;
            }

            .redbox {
                border: 2px solid darkred;
                background: red;
                height: 75px;
                width: 75px;
            }
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/YBAfF/

Comment: My apologies, this isn't supported in IE7

Comment: I removed the need to support IE7 (after re-check, turned out we needed IE8)

Answer (score 1):

Add `text-align:right` to parent div, it makes child elements to align right side. Now add float:left to `#text`

```
#parent {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: block;
  line-height: 400px;
  height: 400px; text-align:right

}

#text {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px dashed black;
  height: 100%; text-align:left; float:left
}

#logo {
  border: 1px dashed black;
  height: 90%;
  line-height: 90%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
}

#logo img {
  border: 1px dashed red;
  height: 100%;
}
​
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/x5sN9/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sample [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kYrCB/) and the same code below. When you set the height of an element, you can set the same line-height to nested elements and they'll expand to the height. Vertically centering the content.

HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="left">left</div>
<div id="right">right</div>
</div>​
```

CSS

```
#wrapper{
    margin:0 auto;
    width 960px;
    background: #eee;
    height:50px;
}
#left{
    float:left;
    background:#ccc;
    line-height:50px;
}
#right{
    float:right;
    background:#ddd;
    line-height:50px;
}
```

​

Comment: For me things got messy when I added an image so this doesn't work for me. Thanks though.

Comment: Check out this updated jsfiddle with an image that's aligned http://jsfiddle.net/kYrCB/2/ the text on he left is typically about 20px heigh, so the top and bottom margin are 40px giving you that 100px height which the wrapper is set to

Answer (score 0):

You should add a wrapper around the elements you want to center and float them inside the wrapper. Something like that:

HTML

```
<div class="center">
  <p class="left">Some text goes here</p>
  <img src="/path/toimage" alt="My image" class="right">
</div>
```

CSS

```
.center {
  margin:0 auto;
  width: 400px;
}
.right {
  float: right;
}
.right {
  float: left;
}
```

Of course, this is a very simple example. You can change the values and CSS according to your needs.